# Is storing a Uint8Array in IndexedDB efficient?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I was wondering if storing a uint8array in indexedDB is as storage-efficient as storing an arrayBuffer with the same data. That's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Uint8Array is just a "view" of an ArrayBuffer. The underlying data is the same blob of binary data, which when serialized for storage in IndexedDB will be exactly the same, barring some different metadata. So, no, there is significant difference in the storage efficiency of one over the other.

The question comes down to how the two are serialized for storage in IndexedDB. You can see how that's done here: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/structured-data.html#structuredserializeinternal

Comment: Just updated with a link to the technical implementation details.